# exterior door to landing mininum height

Tags: doors, exterior, stairs

does anyone know what the minimum exterior door to landing height is in MA. I know the max is 7 3/4 but I dont know the minimum. I'm getting conflicting information that it can't be less than 6 inches, ideally I wanted to go 4 inches.

TIA, P

Comment: Ummm.... What about wheelchairs? Wouldn't the minimum be zero?

Comment: International building code has a minimum stair riser height of 4 inches in some cases. Is that what you're referring to? I'm not sure whether a threshold qualifies as a step.

Comment: That said, local code questions are off topic here. Call your jurisdiction's inspection office.

Comment: There's anly stairs to get to the house, so the wheelchair thing didnt occur to me. Just trying to figure out how long of a riser I can go on the landing to the exterior door threshold/finished floor. More specifically if there is a minimum or not.

Comment: @isherwood Where does it say “local code questions are off topic here” ?

Comment: [Note, the following are considered off-topic: Local building codes or advice limited to your area.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the maximum vertical threshold height is 7.75” at a LANDING, if it’s not an accessible unit. That is to say, from the top of the landing to the top of the threshold it can only be 7.75” max. (So, the distance from top of landing to top of floor must be less.) (See ICC 1008.1.6, Exception)

The distance could be zero, so your requested 4” is acceptable.

Btw, a landing is required to be the width of the stairway or door which ever is greater and a minimum of 36” in the direction of travel. (See ICC 1008.1.5)

Comment: Lee Sam thank you for your reply. I knew the minimum width of 36 wasn't sure about the min from the exterior door to the landing. I knew this can be different than the other steps after the landing but I was confused about the minimum landing height. Thanks again.